# Fix repeated comment due to change line in \pdfmarkupcomment

Tags: pdftex, pdf, pdfcomment

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[author={anon}]{pdfcomment}

\begin{document}
    \pdfmarkupcomment[markup=Highlight,color=green]{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,}{comment} quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
\end{document}
```

The resulted highlighted comment:

[[image: repeated highlight comment1]

It actually not a bug, but a feature if opened in browser I think, because it make the comment appear in whenever line we hover our mouse. But, I think some people prefer Adobe Reader or any reader that support list of comment. How to make it only appear once in Adobe Reader comment list? Or is it Adobe problem and other reader will automatically fix it?

Comment: pdfcomment creates two annotations so the reader is right to show two comments.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer So it is actually intended. How to make it appear only once, from the perspective of \pdfcomment? Because if I use manual highlight from adobe, I can highlight multiple line with single comment.

Comment: well pdfcomment would have to combine both into one and use the correct quadpoints. That is not impossible but someone has to write the code. Send a feature request to the author.

Comment: Do you know how to do feature request for that library? I can't find any lead in github repository.

Comment: ctan https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcomment mentions the home page, and the home page leads to https://bitbucket.org/kleberj/pdfcomment/wiki/Home